# navigation between templates using directives angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to navigate between different html templates on click of the button.

I have main html and sub html.

Main.html:

```
<div id="main"></div>
```

Sub.html:

```
<div id="sub"></div>
```

Index.html:

```
<my-clicker on-click="ButtonClicked($event)">
            <button class="new_btn">Click Me</button>
        </my-clicker>
```

Directive Code:

```
app.directive('myClicker', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                onClick: "&"
            },
            link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
                var button = $('.new_btn');
                button.bind("click", $scope.onClick);
                element.append(button);
            }
        };
    });
```

Controller:

```
$scope.ButtonClicked = function($event) {
            alert('hai');
        };
```

Now how do I add my template urls to the button click event. Can anyone please help me out with the sample how we can achieve this scenario.

Comment: Not quite sure what you are trying to do here. What is the usecase? Are you trying to simply go to a new url or do you want to swap one specific dom-element out with a new template? Add some more info about what you are trying to do and I will try to answer.

Comment: @ErikHonn: Usecase is I need to swap the specific dom element with a new template.

Answer (score 0):

So according to the comments the usecase here is to swap out one specific part of the DOM when clicking a button.

In this case you don't need a custom directive, you should use ng-include. The ng-include directive is placed on a div (or other dom element) and makes that element load its content from a specified template. You can specify this template as a variable and when you want to swap the content of the div you just change the variable.

Here is an example:

```
<div id="swappable-content-area" ng-include src="currentTemplate">
    <!-- The content will appear here -->
</div>

<button ng-click="currentTemplate = 'mytemplate.html'">Template 1</button>
<button ng-click="currentTemplate = 'myothertemplate.html'">Template 2</button>
```

The buttons could of course be a part of the included template.